# How can I add withCredentials=true to Jquery .load()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm fairly new to Jquery,

I am fetching some content from another domain with Jquery .load() and I would need to use the session cookies. Anyone know how I can add the "withCredentials = true" to .load() function?

e.g.

```
$('#displayPics').load('https://example.com/somecontent.php').fadeIn("slow");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.load()` is a very stripped down shorthand function which doesn't allow you to pass settings.

Just recreate what it does but with `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://example.com/somecontent.php',
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function (data, status) {
    $('#displayPics').html(data.response).fadeIn();
  } 
});
```

Thinking about it though, there's a possibility you could use `$.ajaxSetup()`, see if it works with load (haven't personally tried them together). Put this before you call your load function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Bear in mind that this will affect all AJAX queries coming from jQuery, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I just created the call with ajax and it worked. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Good first question btw